# CSS animation on mac vs windows

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to create a spinner animation but i've encountered some issues with the difference between windows and mac displays.

The animation is a pretty basic circular spinner created with html and css

```
<div class="cow-spinner">
 <span></span>
 <span></span> 
 <span></span>
 <span></span> 
</div>
```

and some basic css:

```
.cow-spinner {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
.cow-spinner span {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  margin: 6px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: cow-spin 1.2s ease-in-out infinite;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}
.cow-spinner span:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -0.45s;
}
.cow-spinner span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.3s;
}
.cow-spinner span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -0.15s;
}
@keyframes cow-spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

The animation itself works perfectly, with a working example here: https://codepen.io/fatoilyguy/pen/oaZMMp

My issue is that on mac the circle itself has smooth edges with consistent width like so:
[image]

but on windows, the circle is pixelated and has weird width variations:

[image]

From what I can see, there is no difference between browsers on either platform. Is there any way i could prevent this difference from happening between platforms?

Comment: Does your Mac have a retina display?

Comment: It's subtle, but I see the same pixelation on my (non-retina) mac, and the edges of the circle look a tiny bit "lumpy" which I believe is what you mean by the "weird width variations". It appears to be the antialiasing from the multiple elements adding together, creating a thicker edge when the elements overlap.   I don't know how to prevent this, sorry, but it doesn't appear to be an OS-based difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a `SVG` approach and check if the rendering it's good everywhere

```css
   
.loader {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transform: rotateZ(0deg); 
  animation: rotate 1.5s linear infinite;
}

svg {
  max-width: 140px;
  max-height: 140px;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9bc;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke-dasharray: 301px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 200px;
  animation: path 1.5s linear 0s infinite;
}

@keyframes path {
  60%  { stroke-dashoffset: 40px;  }
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 200px; }
}


@keyframes rotate {
  100% { transform: rotateZ(360deg) }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <svg viewport="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <path d="M 50, 50 m -48, 0 a 48,48 0 1,0 96,0 a 48,48 0 1,0 -96,0" />
  </svg>
</div>
```